# Import OpenStreetMaps data fails

Tags: postgresql

I work in project of geocoding. So i want to import the OpenStreetMaps Data. I created a database and name it `nominatim` and i tried this command:

```
sudo ./utils/setup.php --osm-file morocco-latest.osm.pbf --all –osm2pgsql-cache 18000 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

It shows me this message:

> `CREATE DB
>   ERROR: database already exists ( pgsql : // @/nominatim)`

Then I delete my database `nominatim` it shows this error message :

> `ERROR: unable to find /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sq`

BTW i installed `postgres` with all needed packages.

Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.